# Powershell: Using psexec with UNC path gives "access is denied"

Tags: powershell, remote-access, psexec

I am trying to run a powershell command like this:

> psexec \\MachineB "\\MachineB\drops\Func2WebSiteOnline.bat"

I get this error:

> PsExec could not start \\MachineB\drops\Func2WebSiteOnline.bat on
>   MachineB: Access is denied.

I have tried the following things:

1. run powershell in "Administrator" mode
2. Run the powershell command with "-u Domain\user -p password" params

Neither of those help.  However, I can run simple commands against machineB like this:

> psexec \\MachineB net stop dcache

and that works just fine.

Any thoughts on how I can run that batch file above against MachineB?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a somewhat unconventional way to solve it.

> psexec \\MachineB -u domain\user -p password cmd /c "cd /d
>   I:\drops\Func2 && func2web.bat"